# Eloquent testing models

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a class which uses Laravel's Eloquent ORM (I am not using entire framework).

For some reasons I like Eloquent more than other ORMs but, I am having trouble to figure out how to test few things.

Example:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    $this->loadModel();

    return $this->blogModel->title;
}


private function loadModel()
{
    if($this->blogModel) {
        return;
    }

    $this->blogModel = BlogModel::find($this->id);
}
```

I would like to mock `BlogModel::find($this->id);`
And test, it gets call exactly once. (or none when no action is made).

The point of class is to require only blog's ID and load the rest only when needed. Is there some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle here is like in all testing. Calling a static function on `BlogModel` straight in the code is depending on that class which isn't good when writing tests. You want to **inject dependencies** into your class so you can test your class in isolation. You can do this in two fashions (unless using a Dependency Injection Container), either you use constructor injection or inject them using a setter.

### Constructor injection

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $blogModelClass;

    public function __construct(BlogModel $blogModelClass) 
    {
        $this->blogModelClass = $blogModel;
    }

    private function loadModel()
    {
        if($this->blogModel) {
            return;
        }

        $this->blogModel = $this->blogModelClass->find($this->id);
    }
}
```

### Setter injection

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $blogModelClass;

    public function setBlogModelClass(BlogModel $blogModelClass) 
    {
        $this->blogModelClass = $blogModel;
    }

    private function loadModel()
    {
        if($this->blogModel) {
            return;
        }

        $this->blogModel = $this->blogModelClass->find($this->id);
    }
}
```

### Testing

Now you're able to either inject the dependency in the constructor or using a getter, so these are your options

```
// Constructor injection
$someClass = new SomeClass(new BlogModel);

// Setter injection
$someClass = new SomeClass();
$someClass->setBlogModelClass(new BlogModel);
```

When writing your test you can now easily insert a mock object instead and mock the response for it.

Comment: The constructor solution occured to me, but it would be against my plans for the class. Totally forgot the setter way. Thanks.